# Can we check if a user's In App Purchase has been refunded by Apple?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

**Situation:**
- User makes an IAP and is awarded some content, we store the users device id to ensure they can access this content whenever they want.
- User decided they do not like the content, so they call Apple and get a refund.
- User can still access the content, even though they have been refunded for their IAP

**Problem:**
We don't want the user to be able to access this content anymore. This could become a loophole that they would take advantage of. (unlock content, then get refunded and keep their access to said content)

**Question:**
Is there any way for us to check if a user has been refunded for an IAP with either their transactionId, transactionReceipt, or any other information we may have?

*For Reference, I've read the [StoreKitGuide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), it did not mention this case.*

Comment: How did you finally handle this situation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. There is no way to revoke access to content if they have been refunded. I believe this is by design. It is the same with App Store refunds; if someone buys an app and then asks Apple for a refund, Apple does not stop the user from continuing to use the app.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this is unacceptable as the unlocked content is quite expensive and would surely become a loophole users would take. Looks like I'll have to speak with Apple about my options.

Comment: it's been like that for three years. Few developers have complained; I'll doubt Apple changes policies. They rely on user trust; most people buying your app aren't going to get a refund to skip paying a couple of dollars.

Comment: We're talking about between $100-$200, not "a couple of dollars" -- Apple has been helpful, thanks.

Comment: Even if it's $200, I think Apple's train of thought is that your customers should be fully satisfied, and your returns from the majority that will not refund will easily exceed any refunds made.

Comment: You say "Apple has been helpful", what was their response?

Comment: Im writing a voip app that sells minutes through in app purchases.  I   dont want to offer a $200 package if someone could call up apple and say they purchased the wrong one, got a refund, and still were able to use all the minutes.  I heard you could periodically check the receipt for an expired flag, which indicated if the purchase was refunded.  Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: This thread has been really helpful to me. I did notice that it is more than 5 years old. Has anything changed in the last 5 years to fix this problem?

Comment: @AlBeebe `I heard you could periodically check the receipt for an expired flag, which indicated if the purchase was refunded` Can you elaborate on this please? How can the devs check the receipt of a purchase repeatedly? Isn't the receipt only redeemed once instantly after the purchase?

Answer (score 3):

No. you cannot stop user to access. Apple does not stop user to use that feature after refund

Answer (score 3):

Below a recent answer from the overbearing Apple!!!

---

At April 11
Hello Joe,

Thanks for your quick reply at first.

I think there were some misunderstandings.  We understand that you must protect the user information. And we do not require any user info.  We do not require any user's information---- iTunes account, User Name, email address and other information about himself/herself.

We require only one data----- transaction id (named "transactionIdentify" in your code), for example  "1000000033409668"  (this transaction id is a record at March 13).

A user buys a product from IAP, you will generate a "transaction id" and send it to us. This transaction id is stored in our database then.  Now he/she gets refunds from you, so please send the transaction id to us. Let us know which one in the game canceled the IAP.

When a refund occurs, we think you should provide the transaction id to us. With these data, we could make a more fair service for all players. If you do not do it, more and more players will use your refund mechanism to get game items without real payment. You and we will lose money then.  We think it is very important.

Regards,

### Baibo

At April 12
Hello Baibo,

Thank you for following up with me regarding the refund transaction data.

We will not be able to provide you with the refund transaction data you have requested as it is not a feature or benefit provided to you per the contracts you have agreed to.

To view your paid applications contract and review your membership benefits, please access the contracts, tax and banking module within iTunes Connect:

http://itunesconnect.apple.com

If you are not happy with large refunds, you may want to consider adjusting the price of your in-app purchases as we will not be able to provide you with the refund transaction data in the future.

---

Answer (score 2):

According to an answer one of my users received from Apple, refunding an app means they will no longer receive updates to the app, but doesn't remove the app from the device. IAP appears to work the same.

I am wondering if there is not a way by using restoreCompletedTransactions to check for the iAP purchase, but this would pop up a request for the user's iTunes password, so its use is limited.